# При создании поста в Панели Администратора выдаёт ошибку. AdminLTE Version 2.3.7, Laravel 5.4.36

Tags: php, laravel

(1/1) ErrorException
join(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters

in SlugService.php (line 137)

at HandleExceptions->handleError()

at join()
in SlugService.php (line 137)

Post.php

```
    public static function add($fields)
    {
        $post = new static;
        $post->fill($fields);
        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->save();

        return $post;
    }
```

Comment: Это не тот кусок кода, где проблема

Comment: Написано: проблема в файле SlugService.php на строке 137. Зачем надо давать кусок Post.php - совершенно не ясно

Comment: Это файл отвечающий за вывод ошибки - то есть при любой подобной проблеме будит выводиться путь  к нему, и поменяв его так-же всё будит не работать.

Comment: Нет, SlugService не отвечает за вывод ошибки.......что за путь ты меняешь?